# iOS IBOutlet UILabel Duplicate

Tags: ios, objective-c

[Screenshot](http://segmentfault.com/img/bVkOUY/view)

In the screenshot, the label after fork and knife render twice. The label is budgetLabel in following code. Just IBOutlet to a label in storyboard, not created in code. How cloud this happened? I have no idea.

```
//
//  LogViewController.m
//  Calorie
//
//  Created by 但 江 on 13-12-8.
//  Copyright (c) 2013年 Dan Thought Studio. All rights reserved.
//

#import "DTLogsViewController.h"
#import "DTAlertView.h"
#import "DTBlankView.h"
#import "DTCircleView.h"
#import "DTCalendarHeader.h"
#import "DTLogHeader.h"
#import "DTLogCell.h"
#import "DTRectangleView.h"
#import "DTPercentView.h"
#import "DTTheme.h"
#import "DTUserDefaults.h"
#import "DTDataManager.h"
#import "DTUnitConverter.h"
#import "DTContextObserver.h"
#import "NSDate+Extend.h"
#import "DTDevice.h"
#import "DTConstant.h"
#import "DTLog.h"

static NSString * const DTLogHeaderIdentifier = @"LogHeader";
static NSString * const DTLogCellIdentifier = @"LogCell";
static NSString * const DTCalendarCellIdentifier = @"CalendarCell";

@interface DTLogsViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, DTContextObserverDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *burnCircleLeading;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *burnCircleTrailing;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet DTCircleView *intakeCircleView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet DTCircleView *burnCircleView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet DTCircleView *netCircleView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *intakeLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *burnLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *netLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *intakeUnit;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *burnUnit;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *netUnit;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *dayLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *budgetImageView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *budgetLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *recommendLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet DTPercentView *percentView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet DTCalendarHeader *calendarHeader;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) DTBlankView *blankView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *brands;
@property (nonatomic, strong) DTContextObserver *observer;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat calendarCellWidth;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat calendarCellSpace;

@end

@implementation DTLogsViewController

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:DTPersistentStoreIsReadyNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:DTUserDefaultsOnlyUnitChangedNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:DTUserDefaultsExcludeUnitChangedNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"notepad-full"];

    self.date = [NSDate new];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(initDatas) name:DTPersistentStoreIsReadyNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(userDefaultsChanged) name:DTUserDefaultsOnlyUnitChangedNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(userDefaultsChanged) name:DTUserDefaultsExcludeUnitChangedNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(significantTimeChanged) name:UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];

    UIBarButtonItem *calendarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"calendar-normal"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(calendar)];
    UIBarButtonItem *tomorrowButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right-arrow-line"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(tomorrow)];
    UIBarButtonItem *yesterdayButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"left-arrow-line"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(yesterday)];
    UIBarButtonItem *todayButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"BackToToday", @"Back To Today Text") style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(today)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = calendarButtonItem;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[tomorrowButtonItem, yesterdayButtonItem, todayButtonItem];

    self.intakeCircleView.color = [DTTheme orangeColor];
    self.burnCircleView.color = [DTTheme greenColor];
    self.netCircleView.color = [DTTheme purpleColor];
    self.percentView.color = [DTTheme purpleColor];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[DTLogHeader class] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:DTLogHeaderIdentifier];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[DTLogCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:DTLogCellIdentifier];
    self.calendarCellWidth = CalendarItemWidthPhoneOther;
    self.calendarCellSpace = CalendarItemSpacePhoneOther;
    if ([DTDevice isPhone6Plus]) {
        self.calendarCellWidth = CalendarItemWidthPhone6Plus;
        self.calendarCellSpace = CalendarItemSpacePhone6Plus;
    } else if ([DTDevice isPhone6]) {
        self.calendarCellWidth = CalendarItemWidthPhone6;
        self.calendarCellSpace = CalendarItemSpacePhone6;
    } else if ([DTDevice isPadPortrait]) {
        self.calendarCellWidth = CalendarItemWidthPadPortrait;
        self.calendarCellSpace = CalendarItemSpacePadPortrait;
    } else if ([DTDevice isPadLandscape]) {
        self.calendarCellWidth = CalendarItemWidthPadLandscape;
        self.calendarCellSpace = CalendarItemSpacePadLandscape;
    }
    [self.calendarHeader.previousMonthButton removeTarget:self action:@selector(previousMonth) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.calendarHeader.previousMonthButton addTarget:self action:@selector(previousMonth) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.calendarHeader.nextMonthButton removeTarget:self action:@selector(nextMonth) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.calendarHeader.nextMonthButton addTarget:self action:@selector(nextMonth) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.tableView.hidden = NO;
    self.calendarHeader.hidden = YES;
    self.collectionView.hidden = YES;

    if ([DTDataManager sharedInstance].status == DTDataManagerStatusPersistentStoreIsReady) {
        [self initDatas];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame);
    CGFloat burnCircleSpace = (width - CGRectGetWidth(self.burnCircleView.frame) * 3) / 4;
    self.burnCircleLeading.constant = burnCircleSpace;
    self.burnCircleTrailing.constant = burnCircleSpace;
    [self.calendarHeader reloadWithWidth:width weekdayWidth:self.calendarCellWidth weekdaySpace:self.calendarCellSpace];

    if ([DTUserDefaults getAge] == 0) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LogToWelcome" sender:self];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [self.tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        self.calendarCellWidth = CalendarItemWidthPadPortrait;
        self.calendarCellSpace = CalendarItemSpacePadPortrait;
    } else {
        self.calendarCellWidth = CalendarItemWidthPadLandscape;
        self.calendarCellSpace = CalendarItemSpacePadLandscape;
    }
    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame);
    CGFloat burnCircleSpace = (width - CGRectGetWidth(self.burnCircleView.frame) * 3) / 4;
    self.burnCircleLeading.constant = burnCircleSpace;
    self.burnCircleTrailing.constant = burnCircleSpace;
    [self.calendarHeader reloadWithWidth:width weekdayWidth:self.calendarCellWidth weekdaySpace:self.calendarCellSpace];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];

    self.blankView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.topLayoutGuide.length, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) - self.topLayoutGuide.length - self.bottomLayoutGuide.length);
}

#pragma mark - Collection View Data Source and Delegate

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSDate *firstDayOfMonth = [self.date firstDayOfMonth];
    NSInteger offset = [firstDayOfMonth weekday] - 1;
    NSInteger numberOfDaysInMonth = [firstDayOfMonth numberOfDaysInMonth];
    return offset + numberOfDaysInMonth;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:DTCalendarCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDate *firstDayOfMonth = [self.date firstDayOfMonth];
    NSInteger offset = [firstDayOfMonth weekday] - 1;
    if (indexPath.row < offset) {
        cell.hidden = YES;
    } else {
        cell.hidden = NO;
        NSInteger day = indexPath.row + 1 - offset;
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *dayOfMonthComponents = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:firstDayOfMonth];
        [dayOfMonthComponents setDay:day];
        NSDate *dayOfMonth = [calendar dateFromComponents:dayOfMonthComponents];
        UILabel *label = cell.contentView.subviews[0];
        UIImageView *imageView = cell.contentView.subviews[1];
        UIColor *labelTextColor;
        UIColor *cellBackgroundColor;
        if ([dayOfMonth sameDay:self.date]) {
            labelTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cellBackgroundColor = [DTTheme calendarCurrentDateColor];
        } else if ([dayOfMonth sameDay:[NSDate new]]) {
            labelTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cellBackgroundColor = [DTTheme orangeColor];
        } else {
            labelTextColor = [DTTheme darkGrayColor];
            cellBackgroundColor = [DTTheme calendarDefaultDateColor];
        }
        label.textColor = labelTextColor;
        cell.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColor;
        label.text = [dayOfMonth formatDate:@"d"];
        if ([[DTDataManager sharedInstance] existedLogsWithDate:[dayOfMonth formatDayOfYear]]) {
            imageView.hidden = NO;
            imageView.tintColor = labelTextColor;
            imageView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle-full"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        } else {
            imageView.hidden = YES;
        }
    }
    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(self.calendarCellWidth, self.calendarCellWidth);
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.calendarCellSpace;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.calendarCellSpace;
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    CGFloat padding = (CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) - self.calendarCellWidth * 7 - self.calendarCellSpace * 6) / 2;
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, padding, padding, padding);
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDate *firstDayOfMonth = [self.date firstDayOfMonth];
    NSInteger offset = [firstDayOfMonth weekday] - 1;
    if (indexPath.row >= offset) {
        NSInteger day = indexPath.row + 1 - offset;
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *dayOfMonthComponents = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:firstDayOfMonth];
        [dayOfMonthComponents setDay:day];
        self.date = [calendar dateFromComponents:dayOfMonthComponents];
        [self initDatas];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table View Data Source and Delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.brands.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *logs = self.brands[section];
    return logs.count;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    DTLogHeader *header = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:DTLogHeaderIdentifier];
    NSArray *logs = self.brands[section];
    DTLog *log = logs.firstObject;
    if ([log isNoBrand]) {
        header.contentTitleLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"NoBrand", @"No Brand Text");
    } else {
        header.contentTitleLabel.text = log.brand;
    }
    return header;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DTLogCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DTLogCellIdentifier];
    NSArray *logs = self.brands[indexPath.section];
    DTLog *log = logs[indexPath.row];
    UIColor *color = log.isFood ? [DTTheme orangeColor] : [DTTheme greenColor];
    NSString *modifier = log.isFood ? @"+" : @"-";
    int calorie = [DTUserDefaults isUnitStandard] ? log.calorieStandard : log.calorieMetric;
    ((DTRectangleView *)cell.contentRectangleView).color = color;
    cell.contentNameLabel.text = log.name;
    cell.contentUnitLabel.text = log.unit;
    cell.contentCalorieLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d %@", modifier, calorie, [DTUserDefaults calorieUnit]];
    cell.contentCalorieLabel.textColor = color;
    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSArray *logs = self.brands[indexPath.section];
        DTLog *log = logs[indexPath.row];
        [[DTDataManager sharedInstance] removeLog:log];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Actions

- (void)calendar {
    if (self.tableView.hidden) {
        self.tableView.hidden = NO;
        self.calendarHeader.hidden = YES;
        self.collectionView.hidden = YES;
    } else {
        self.tableView.hidden = YES;
        self.calendarHeader.hidden = NO;
        self.collectionView.hidden = NO;
    }
}

- (void)today {
    self.date = [NSDate new];
    [self initDatas];
}

- (void)yesterday {
    self.date = [self.date yesterday];
    [self initDatas];
}

- (void)tomorrow {
    self.date = [self.date tomorrow];
    [self initDatas];
}

- (void)previousMonth {
    self.date = [self.date previousMonth];
    [self initDatas];
}

- (void)nextMonth {
    self.date = [self.date nextMonth];
    [self initDatas];
}

#pragma mark - ManagedObjectContextObserverDelegate

- (void)contextObserverDidInsert {
    [self initDatas];
}

- (void)contextObserverDidDelete {
    [self initDatas];
}

#pragma mark - Private Helper Method

- (void)initDatas {
    NSString *date = [self.date formatDayOfYear];
    NSMutableArray *brands = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSArray *logObjects = [[DTDataManager sharedInstance] findLogsWithDate:date];
    DTLog *lastLog;
    NSMutableArray *logs;
    for (NSManagedObject *logObject in logObjects) {
        DTLog *log = [[DTLog alloc] initWithManagedObject:logObject];
        if (!lastLog || ![lastLog.brand isEqual:log.brand]) {
            logs = [NSMutableArray new];
            [brands addObject:logs];
            lastLog = log;
        }
        [logs addObject:log];
    }
    self.brands = brands;
    [self reloadView];
    if (self.observer) {
        [[DTDataManager sharedInstance] resetLogContextObserver:self.observer date:date];
    } else {
        self.observer = [[DTDataManager sharedInstance] logContextObserverWithDate:date];
        self.observer.delegate = self;
    }
}

- (void)reloadView {
    [self reloadTotal];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    self.calendarHeader.monthLabel.text = [self.date localMonth];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

- (void)reloadTotal {
    NSString *calorieUnit = [DTUserDefaults calorieUnit];
    int recommend = [DTUnitConverter dailyIntake];
    int intake = 0;
    int burn = 0;
    for (NSArray *logs in self.brands) {
        for (DTLog *log in logs) {
            int calorie = [DTUserDefaults isUnitStandard] ? log.calorieStandard : log.calorieMetric;
            if (log.isFood) {
                intake += calorie;
            } else {
                burn += calorie;
            }
        }
    }
    int neat = intake - burn;
    int suggestion = recommend - neat;
    NSString *imageName = @"utensils-full";
    NSString *modifier = @"";
    if (suggestion > 0) {
        modifier = @"+";
    } else if (suggestion < 0) {
        imageName = @"weights-full";
    }
    CGFloat percent = neat * 1.0 / recommend;
    if (percent > 1.0) {
        percent = 1.0;
    }
    self.intakeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", intake];
    self.burnLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", burn];
    self.netLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", neat];
    self.intakeUnit.text = calorieUnit;
    self.burnUnit.text = calorieUnit;
    self.netUnit.text = calorieUnit;
    self.dayLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [self.date localDate], [self.date localWeekday]];
    self.budgetImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    self.budgetLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d %@", modifier, suggestion, calorieUnit];
    self.recommendLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@", recommend, calorieUnit];
    self.percentView.percent = percent;
}

- (void)userDefaultsChanged {
    [self reloadView];
}

- (void)significantTimeChanged {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate new];
    NSDate *significantTime = [DTUserDefaults getSignificantTime];
    if (significantTime) {
        NSDateComponents *currentTimeComponents = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit)
                                              fromDate:currentTime];
        NSDateComponents *significantTimeComponents = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit)
                                                              fromDate:significantTime];
        if (significantTimeComponents.day != currentTimeComponents.day
            || significantTimeComponents.month != currentTimeComponents.month
            || significantTimeComponents.year != currentTimeComponents.year) {
            self.date = [NSDate new];
            [self initDatas];
            [DTUserDefaults setSignificantTime:currentTime];
        }
    } else {
        self.date = [NSDate new];
        [self initDatas];
        [DTUserDefaults setSignificantTime:currentTime];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: There is not enough information in this question.  There is no screenshot or context to what the problem is.

Comment: You should probably write down more about what's going on in this view controller.

Comment: I don`t have enough reputation to publish image. This is a [screenshot link](http://segmentfault.com/img/bVkOUY/view). Every time user change date to see total calorie for this day. It will find the data in core data and then invoke reloadTotal to update view. So the budgetLabel render twice.

Comment: Did you check that you don't have two labels in the same place in the Interface Builder and you are just changing one of them and the other is staying the same?

Comment: @rr1g0 I am pretty much sure I don`t have two labels.

Comment: The problem is just because not render view in main thread. Notification may came from background thread.

Answer (score 0):

One problem might be that you keep reloading the label.

Instead try this:

```
if (!self.budgetLabel) {

    // Put in here the code you are using to allocate your label
    self.budgetLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    // ...

    // Code to set up the label
}
```

Then put the label set text

```
self.budgetLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d %@", modifier, suggestion, calorieUnit];
```

Changing the text of the label shouldn't reload or add the label. If you are having this issue then it probably means you keep adding the label over and over again or at least allocating it again and again.

The question is difficult to understand so if you can make the exact problem clearer then it will be easier for us to troubleshoot.

Comment: What do you mean by renders twice?

Comment: First the label showed "5678 Cal". After user choose another day. The label showed "7896 Cal" at the same place. But "5678 Cal" is not gone.